# R - Create new indices based on group_id and conditional statement

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am working with a data frame (lets call is MyData) looking like below. What I want to do is to group by PatientKey and create a new Id called NewID. Every time for the same PatientKey that the TimeBetweenTests is > 14, the new Id should increase by 1, and stay on that particular new value until a new PatientKey shows up OR for the same patientKey a new TimeBetweenTests > 14 shows up.

```
PatientKey             TimeBetweenTests     NewId        
1                      0                    NewId should be 1 (first patient)
1                      0                    NewId should be 1
1                      1                    NewId should be 1                                                                
1                      2                    NewId should be 1
2                      3                    NewId should be 2 (new patient)                                                                          
3                      4                    NewId should be 3 (new patient)      
3                      16                   NewId should be 4 (same patient but TimeBetweenTests > 14)                                                                                              
3                      80                   NewId should be 5 (same patient but TimeBetweenTests > 14)
4                      3                    NewId should be 6 (new patient)
4                      0                    NewId should be 6 (new patient)                                                                            
4                      90                   NewId should be 7 (same patient but TimeBetweenTests > 14)        
4                      110                  NewId should be 8 (same patient but TimeBetweenTests > 14) 
5                      3                    NewId should be 9 (new patient)
5                      3                    NewId should be 9
5                      3                    NewId should be 9

etc
```

I have tried using dplyr for this but the problem is that the subsequent values does not change when I try code similar to:

MyData <- MyData %>% group_by(PatientKey) %>% mutate(NewId = ifelse(TimeBetweenTests > 14, lag(NewId), NewId))

Anyone has a convenient dplyr or data.table solution for this, alternatively a for loop approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(NewID = cumsum(lag(PatientKey, default = 0) != PatientKey | TimeBetweenTests > 14)
```

Output

```
   PatientKey TimeBetweenTests NewID
        <dbl>            <dbl> <int>
 1          1                0     1
 2          1                0     1
 3          1                1     1
 4          1                2     1
 5          2                3     2
 6          3                4     3
 7          3               16     4
 8          3               80     5
 9          4                3     6
10          4                0     6
11          4               90     7
12          4              110     8
13          5                3     9
14          5                3     9
15          5                3     9
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that it only changes from the first time there is a value with more than 14. It should ALSO change ID when there is a new patientKey.

Comment: @PontusHedberg Hi, check the update. Is this what you need?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort, however still a problem and does not result in the correct cumulative indexation based on new patient and/or a value > 14. Best Pontus

Comment: @PontusHedberg Perhaps I misunderstand your point. You need the cumulative index to increase 1 whenever there is a change in `PatientKey` or `TimeBetweenTests > 14`, right? Then, what if all two conditions happen at once (for instance, at row 13 of the Input I showed above)? In that case, you want the cumulative index to increase by `1` or `2`?

Comment: Hi! Yes you understand things correctly! If that happens it should increase by 1, not 2. Thanks, Pontus

Comment: @PontusHedberg Then my original post should work, which is `cumsum(lag(PatientKey, default = 0) != PatientKey | TimeBetweenTests > 14)`. The first part (`lag(PatientKey, default = 0) != PatientKey`) gives a `TRUE` whenever there is a change in `PatientKey`. Can you show me a scenario when it doesn't work?

Comment: @PontusHedberg Oh I see, please do this `MyData %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(NewID = cumsum(lag(PatientKey, default = 0) != PatientKey | TimeBetweenTests > 14)` You have to `ungroup` or that script cannot work.

Comment: Problem is that I am working on a VPN server with patient data so can not export but in summary:
What that script is doing is that it starts with ID as 1 (which is right) and then does NOT change index when patientkey changes, but changes index to 2 when it first encounters a row where TimeBetweenTests > 14 and then when it encounters next new patientkey it goes back to 1 and continues like that for the rest of the patient keys. Any idea why? Best,Pontus

Comment: Your final suggestion worked perfect! Thanks a BUNCH!!!!!!